# grep --include="" takes a lot longer than filename

Tags: linux, grep, include

I am trying to `grep` recursively through 100 folders each with 20000-40000 files in them.

If I go into a folder and run :

```
grep -l "Search_String" File_Name_Starts_With* | xargs ls -lt
```

it returns the results, I want, in less than 1 second.

If I run:

```
grep -l --include="File_Name_Starts_With*" "Search_String" | xargs ls -lt
```

it sits there for a long time... 15 min is the longest I have let it sit with no result before cancelling.

I assume I am doing something wrong, as this is my first attempt at this.

Comment: I think with grep you still need to include either a path or filename.. In the second example, you are not doing that so that may explain why grep is taking much longer. Can you try something like: ```grep -l --include="File_Name_Starts_With*" "Search_String" . | xargs ls -lt``` and advise what it provides for output?

Comment: When I search a different folder the first search takes ~50 seconds

Comment: In your second search, you are not providing a directory path or filename as you are the first search. That is your problem

Comment: Trying your suggestion now

Comment: That did the trick! Now, I am dropping back a folder, and searching recursively. Will probably take an hour given how long it takes for each folder.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear that worked, I posted my comment as an answer

Comment: in first case, shell expands `File_Name_Starts_With*` and passes onto grep... you are missing `-r` option with second command... but note that `-r` will search recursively the sub-directories as well but first command where shell expands, it applies only to files within the current directory

Comment: also, to pass filenames to another command, add `-Z` for grep and use `xargs -0`

Comment: After 1.5 hours it still had not returned anything, and I canceled it. I did add -r to search recursively.

Comment: I was able to do a file count, [ls -R | wc -l] returned 1904969. This took about 5 min to complete

Comment: `grep -lr --include="File_Name_Starts_With*" "Search_String" . | xargs ls -lt` - This does work, I verified using sub directories with less files in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure I will place my comment as the answer. In your second search, you need to provide a directory path or a file:

```
grep -l --include="File_Name_Starts_With*" "Search_String" <path_or_file> |
xargs ls -lt
```